# sort an array of objects, with key, which is a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have `array` of `dictionaries`, i want to sort the `array` using the `key` @"date" which is in the format of a `dictionary` like.

```
 "date": {
                "day": 19,
                "month": 5,
                "year": 2014
            },
```

how can i sort the array based on the `key` @"date"??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = (NSDictionary *)o1;
    NSDictionary *dict2 = (NSDictionary *)o2;

    if (![dict1[@"date"][@"year"] isEqualToString:dict2[@"date"][@"year"]])
          return [dict1[@"date"][@"year"] compare:dict2[@"date"][@"year"] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    else {
          // years are equal
          // continue comparing by month, day, etc
    }
}];
```

Only compare based on the keys you want

Comment: I updated my answer show how you could compare by one of the keys. You can use a similar process for the rest